# Can Jira Software's built-in automations add the corresponding calendar quarter to issues based on the created date?

Tags: if-statement, automation, jira, rules

My problem: my automation attempt to add values for a custom field based on the issues' created date with a scheduled IF-ELSE component isn't quite good enough yet. It updated far too many issues. (And no, I can't use Scriptrunner.)

I have a custom field "Quarter" with the pre-populated (dropdown) of the obvious values: Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4. The field purpose is just to make it handy for less-techy users (I myself am fairly low tech, not a programmer) to filter by this in reports and roadmaps and whatnot.

The field just needs to do the following:

- Be a simple drop down so people can update it if it's empty or "wrong"
- Be easy to query and filter by. (Of course date ranges are easy to put in JQL and other reporting, but plans and roadmaps change, so I need this separate object to be able to set regardless of what happens on the issues.)
- Be populated automatically so there's one less field in a form to manually click. (Below is my attempt.)
- People can easily change it if it gets the wrong value here and there, or if the roadmap/plans change.

The logic I made is supposed to do these things (The steps are Trigger=schedule; IF: all, THEN; ELSE-IF, THEN; ELSE-IF, THEN; ELSE-IF, THEN; ELSE, THEN):

1. For issues created in the last year, is the only range I want the rule to even look at. If the issue was created in the last 3 weeks, and the Quarter field is empty, then...
2. If it's created month is in 12, 01, 02, then label "Q1". (Why: usually the business users start planning stuff for "the next quarter" in the month before it, so that's why I padded it by a month. It doesn't have to be exact; off by 1 is better than EMPTY.)
3. If created month in 03, 04, 05, then "Q2"...
4. ..Etc., on through "Q4"
5. ELSE if it fails somehow, put a comment saying "this issue didn't get updated with a quarter. Notify ___" this is my scream test/manipulation check.

I thought this would *probably* work but it partly worked too well and updated WAY beyond that date range. That last ELSE comment got on nearly every issue in the past year.
Also, it didn't get some of the right values on certain dates. Issues created in the first half of the year have "Q3" for instance.

I probably have to put created >= -21d in the ELSE, but I am doing other things wrong too. Things like:

- I'm using the smart-value {{now.month}} to compare to a number in a string, not JQL. So does "{{now.month}} CONTAINS "01 or 02..." even work? How else should I be checking against the month of the created date so I know which value to set?
- Will this loop through these conditions for each issue or will it just stop if it fails one of them? Should I break this up instead of trying to put all these conditions with an action in one rule?

Please help if you can.

Here's the basic relevant JSON:

```
{
  "cloud": true,
  "rules": [
    {
      \
      "name": "Quarterchickendark",
      \
      },
      "created": blabla,
      "updated": yadayada,
      "trigger": {
        "id": "blablabla",
        "component": "TRIGGER",
        "parentId": null,
        "conditionParentId": null,
        "schemaVersion": 1,
        "type": "jira.jql.scheduled",
        "value": {
          "schedule": {
            "cronExpression": "",
            "method": "BASIC",
            "rate": 0,
            "rateInterval": 86400,
            "rRule": "BEGIN:VEVENT\nDTSTART;TZID=[Country]/[Timezone]\nRRULE:FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=3;BYMINUTE=0;BYSECOND=0;INTERVAL=1\nEND:VEVENT\n"
          },
          "jql": "project = [blablabla] and issuetype not in (yadaydada) and created >= -365d  and \"Quarter[Dropdown]\" is empty and sprint is not empty and status not in (backlog, open)",
          "executionMode": "jql",
          "onlyUpdatedIssues": true
        },
        "children": [
          
        ],
        "conditions": [
          
        ],
        "connectionId": null
      },
      "components": [
        {
          "id": "339195765",
          "component": "CONDITION",
          "parentId": null,
          "conditionParentId": null,
          "schemaVersion": 1,
          "type": "jira.condition.container.block",
          "value": null,
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "339195766",
              "component": "CONDITION_BLOCK",
              "parentId": "339195765",
              "conditionParentId": null,
              "schemaVersion": 1,
              "type": "jira.condition.if.block",
              "value": {
                "conditionMatchType": "ALL"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": "339195770",
                  "component": "ACTION",
                  "parentId": "339195766",
                  "conditionParentId": null,
                  "schemaVersion": 10,
                  "type": "jira.issue.edit",
                  "value": {
                    "operations": [
                      {
                        "field": {
                          "type": "NAME",
                          "value": "Quarter"
                        },
                        "fieldType": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:select",
                        "type": "SET",
                        "value": {
                          "type": "NAME",
                          "value": "Q1"
                        }
                      }
                    ],
                    "advancedFields": null,
                    "sendNotifications": true
                  },
                  "children": [
                    
                  ],
                  "conditions": [
                    
                  ],
                  "connectionId": null
                }
              ],
              "conditions": [
                {
                  "id": "339195767",
                  "component": "CONDITION",
                  "parentId": null,
                  "conditionParentId": "339195766",
                  "schemaVersion": 3,
                  "type": "jira.issue.condition",
                  "value": {
                    "selectedField": {
                      "type": "NAME",
                      "value": "Quarter"
                    },
                    "selectedFieldType": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:select",
                    "comparison": "EMPTY",
                    "compareValue": null
                  },
                  "children": [
                    
                  ],
                  "conditions": [
                    
                  ],
                  "connectionId": null
                },
                {
                  "id": "339195768",
                  "component": "CONDITION",
                  "parentId": null,
                  "conditionParentId": "339195766",
                  "schemaVersion": 1,
                  "type": "jira.jql.condition",
                  "value": "created >= -21d",
                  "children": [
                    
                  ],
                  "conditions": [
                    
                  ],
                  "connectionId": null
                },
                {
                  "id": "339195769",
                  "component": "CONDITION",
                  "parentId": null,
                  "conditionParentId": "339195766",
                  "schemaVersion": 1,
                  "type": "jira.comparator.condition",
                  "value": {
                    "first": "{{now.month}}",
                    "second": "12 OR 01 OR 02",
                    "operator": "CONTAINS"
                  },
                  "children": [
                    
                  ],
                  "conditions": [
                    
                  ],
                  "connectionId": null
                }
              ],
              "connectionId": null
            },
            {
              "id": "339195771",
              "component": "CONDITION_BLOCK",
              "parentId": "339195765",
              "conditionParentId": null,
              "schemaVersion": 1,
              "type": "jira.condition.if.block",
              "value": {
                "conditionMatchType": "ALL"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": "339195775",
                  "component": "ACTION",
                  "parentId": "339195771",
                  "conditionParentId": null,
                  "schemaVersion": 10,
                  "type": "jira.issue.edit",
                  "value": {
                    "operations": [
                      {
                        "field": {
                          "type": "NAME",
                          "value": "Quarter"
                        },
                        "fieldType": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:select",
                        "type": "SET",
                        "value": {
                          "type": "NAME",
                          "value": "Q2"
                        }
                      }
                    ],
                    "advancedFields": null,
                    "sendNotifications": true
                  },
                  "children": [
                    
                  ],
                  "conditions": [
                    
                  ],
                  "connectionId": null
                }
              ],
              "conditions": [
                {
                  "id": "339195772",
                  "component": "CONDITION",
                  "parentId": null,
                  "conditionParentId": "339195771",
                  "schemaVersion": 3,
                  "type": "jira.issue.condition",
                  "value": {
                    "selectedField": {
                      "type": "NAME",
                      "value": "Quarter"
                    },
                    "selectedFieldType": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:select",
                    "comparison": "EMPTY",
                    "compareValue": null
                  },
                  "children": [
                    
                  ],
                  "conditions": [
                    
                  ],
                  "connectionId": null
                },
                {
                  "id": "339195773",
                  "component": "CONDITION",
                  "parentId": null,
                  "conditionParentId": "339195771",
                  "schemaVersion": 1,
                  "type": "jira.jql.condition",
                  "value": "created >= -21d",
                  "children": [
                    
                  ],
                  "conditions": [
                    
                  ],
                  "connectionId": null
                },
                {
                  "id": "339195774",
                  "component": "CONDITION",
                  "parentId": null,
                  "conditionParentId": "339195771",
                  "schemaVersion": 1,
                  "type": "jira.comparator.condition",
                  "value": {
                    "first": "{{now.month}}",
                    "second": "03 OR 04 OR 05",
                    "operator": "CONTAINS"
                  },
                  "children": [
                    
                  ],
                  "conditions": [
                    
                  ],
                  "connectionId": null
                }
              ],
              "connectionId": null
            },
            {
              "id": "339195776",
              "component": "CONDITION_BLOCK",
              "parentId": "339195765",
              "conditionParentId": null,
              "schemaVersion": 1,
              "type": "jira.condition.if.block",
              "value": {
                "conditionMatchType": "ALL"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": "339195780",
                  "component": "ACTION",
                  "parentId": "339195776",
                  "conditionParentId": null,
                  "schemaVersion": 10,
                  "type": "jira.issue.edit",
                  "value": {
                    "operations": [
                      {
                        "field": {
                          "type": "NAME",
                          "value": "Quarter"
                        },
                        "fieldType": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:select",
                        "type": "SET",
                        "value": {
                          "type": "NAME",
                          "value": "Q3"
                        }
                      }
                    ],
                    "advancedFields": null,
                    "sendNotifications": true
                  },
                  "children": [
                    
                  ],
                  "conditions": [
                    
                  ],
                  "connectionId": null
                }
              ],
              "conditions": [
                {
                  "id": "339195777",
                  "component": "CONDITION",
                  "parentId": null,
                  "conditionParentId": "339195776",
                  "schemaVersion": 3,
                  "type": "jira.issue.condition",
                  "value": {
                    "selectedField": {
                      "type": "NAME",
                      "value": "Quarter"
                    },
                    "selectedFieldType": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:select",
                    "comparison": "EMPTY",
                    "compareValue": null
                  },
                  "children": [
                    
                  ],
                  "conditions": [
                    
                  ],
                  "connectionId": null
                },
                {
                  "id": "339195778",
                  "component": "CONDITION",
                  "parentId": null,
                  "conditionParentId": "339195776",
                  "schemaVersion": 1,
                  "type": "jira.jql.condition",
                  "value": "created >= -21d",
                  "children": [
                    
                  ],
                  "conditions": [
                    
                  ],
                  "connectionId": null
                },
                {
                  "id": "339195779",
                  "component": "CONDITION",
                  "parentId": null,
                  "conditionParentId": "339195776",
                  "schemaVersion": 1,
                  "type": "jira.comparator.condition",
                  "value": {
                    "first": "{{now.month}}",
                    "second": "06 OR 07 OR 08",
                    "operator": "CONTAINS"
                  },
                  "children": [
                    
                  ],
                  "conditions": [
                    
                  ],
                  "connectionId": null
                }
              ],
              "connectionId": null
            },
            {
              "id": "339195781",
              "component": "CONDITION_BLOCK",
              "parentId": "339195765",
              "conditionParentId": null,
              "schemaVersion": 1,
              "type": "jira.condition.if.block",
              "value": {
                "conditionMatchType": "ALL"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": "339195785",
                  "component": "ACTION",
                  "parentId": "339195781",
                  "conditionParentId": null,
                  "schemaVersion": 10,
                  "type": "jira.issue.edit",
                  "value": {
                    "operations": [
                      {
                        "field": {
                          "type": "NAME",
                          "value": "Quarter"
                        },
                        "fieldType": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:select",
                        "type": "SET",
                        "value": {
                          "type": "NAME",
                          "value": "Q4"
                        }
                      }
                    ],
                    "advancedFields": null,
                    "sendNotifications": true
                  },
                  "children": [
                    
                  ],
                  "conditions": [
                    
                  ],
                  "connectionId": null
                }
              ],
              "conditions": [
                {
                  "id": "339195782",
                  "component": "CONDITION",
                  "parentId": null,
                  "conditionParentId": "339195781",
                  "schemaVersion": 3,
                  "type": "jira.issue.condition",
                  "value": {
                    "selectedField": {
                      "type": "NAME",
                      "value": "Quarter"
                    },
                    "selectedFieldType": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:select",
                    "comparison": "EMPTY",
                    "compareValue": null
                  },
                  "children": [
                    
                  ],
                  "conditions": [
                    
                  ],
                  "connectionId": null
                },
                {
                  "id": "339195783",
                  "component": "CONDITION",
                  "parentId": null,
                  "conditionParentId": "339195781",
                  "schemaVersion": 1,
                  "type": "jira.jql.condition",
                  "value": "created >= -21d",
                  "children": [
                    
                  ],
                  "conditions": [
                    
                  ],
                  "connectionId": null
                },
                {
                  "id": "339195784",
                  "component": "CONDITION",
                  "parentId": null,
                  "conditionParentId": "339195781",
                  "schemaVersion": 1,
                  "type": "jira.comparator.condition",
                  "value": {
                    "first": "{{now.month}}",
                    "second": "09 OR 10 OR 11",
                    "operator": "CONTAINS"
                  },
                  "children": [
                    
                  ],
                  "conditions": [
                    
                  ],
                  "connectionId": null
                }
              ],
              "connectionId": null
            },
            {
              "id": "339195786",
              "component": "CONDITION_BLOCK",
              "parentId": "339195765",
              "conditionParentId": null,
              "schemaVersion": 1,
              "type": "jira.condition.if.block",
              "value": {
                "conditionMatchType": "ALL"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": "339195787",
                  "component": "ACTION",
                  "parentId": "339195786",
                  "conditionParentId": null,
                  "schemaVersion": 1,
                  "type": "jira.issue.comment",
                  "value": {
                    "comment": "This ticket ran rule ######, but didn't match on a quarter.",
                    "publicComment": false,
                    "commentVisibility": null,
                    "sendNotifications": true,
                    "addCommentOnce": true
                  },
                  "children": [
                    
                  ],
                  "conditions": [
                    
                  ],
                  "connectionId": null
                }
              ],
              "conditions": [
                
              ],
              "connectionId": null
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            
          ],
          "connectionId": null
        }
      ],
      "canOtherRuleTrigger": false,
      "notifyOnError": "FIRSTERROR",
      \
    }
  ]
}
```